# An easy to implement HTML5 Form Validation fallback

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, modernizr

I am developing a website for a client that has a contact form. The client wants form errors to pop up on the page rather than open in new pages. This works perfectly in up to date browsers such as Firefox and Chrome (using the 'required' tag) but doesn't work on many others.

Is there an easy-to-implement fallback? I have played around with the Modernizr script but it doesn't change anything.

http://jshjohnson.com/MF/contact.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse HTML5 validation will fail in browsers that don't fully support it (since it's browser dependent).

Modernizr only detects the browsers features.
So you use that to detect if validation isn't supported, and then add fx. a jquery validation library.

You could use a library like http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html

Comment: That isn't easy-to-implement though. Even something like this would be useful but I can't combine the script to work with 3 fields: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp